# Incorrect values being passed from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

The undernoted form gives a series of options to choose using a select form. When the values are retrieved from the $_POST array although the correct id is being passed the value for season simply seems to be the last value in the form.

I have checked my code and league is not being updated anywhere else as far as I can see.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but can't figure it out!

```
<form method = 'post' action = 'index.php?choice=matcht&stage=1'><table width = '50%' border = '1'><thead><tr>
<th>Select</th>
<th>League</th>
<th>Season</th>
</tr></thead>
<tr><td><input type = 'radio' name = 'id' value = '1' ></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'league' value = 'MLB21'  readonly></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'season' value = '12'  readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type = 'radio' name = 'id' value = '25' ></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'league' value = 'MLB21'  readonly></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'season' value = '13'  readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type = 'radio' name = 'id' value = '49' ></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'league' value = 'MLB21'  readonly></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'season' value = '14'  readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type = 'radio' name = 'id' value = '73' ></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'league' value = 'MLB21'  readonly></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'season' value = '15'  readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type = 'radio' name = 'id' value = '97' ></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'league' value = 'MLB21'  readonly></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'season' value = '16'  readonly></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan = '3' align = 'center'><input type = 'submit' name = 'go' value = 'GO'></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP generating the HTML:

```
  $sql='SELECT  `TeamID`, `League`,`Season` FROM teams WHERE `FranchiseID` = 0 GROUP BY `League`,`Season` ORDER BY `League` ASC ,`Season` ASC ';
  $unmatched = $db2->get_results($sql);

    if ($db2->num_rows>0) {

  echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'index.php?choice=matcht&stage=1'>";
  echo "<table width = '50%' border = '1'>";
  echo "<thead><tr>\n";
    echo "<th>Select</th>\n";
    echo "<th>League</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Season</th>\n";
  echo "</tr></thead>\n";
  foreach ( $unmatched as $unmatch )
  {
              // Access data using object syntax
              echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type = 'radio' name = 'id' value = '$unmatch->TeamID' ></td>\n";
                echo "<td><input type = 'text' name = 'league' value = '".$unmatch->League."'  readonly></td>\n";
                echo "<td><input type = 'text' name = 'season' value = '".$unmatch->Season."'  ></td>\n";
              echo "</tr>\n";
  }

  echo "<tr><td colspan = '3' align = 'center'><input type = 'submit' name = 'go' value = 'GO'></td></tr>\n";
  echo "</table>\n";
  echo "</form>\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the text inputs have the same name and the last is overwriting the others.  Use an array and set the index to the `id` so you know which ones to get:

```
<tr><td><input type = 'radio' name = 'id' value = '1' ></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'league[1]' value = 'MLB21'  readonly></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'season[1]' value = '12'  readonly></td>
```

Then you can get it like:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$league = $_POST['league'][$id];
$season = $_POST['season'][$id];
```